# pair of scissors OR scissors

Tags: grammar, plural-forms

1 Please pass me that (scissors).

As I know "pair of scissors" and "scissors" are both correct to use. But in this sentences book has replaced "scissors" with "pair of scissors". Can you please explain why so? 
I have one more doubt whether we use article here "a pair of scissors" or just "pair of scissors".

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Scissors is plural, like trousers, and **that** must be followed by a singular. The sentence can be made grammatically correct in two ways: by adding **pair of** (because a pair is singular), or by replacing **that** by its plural, [those](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/that).

> Please pass me that **pair of** scissors
>   Please pass me **those** scissors

These are both grammatically correct but, as this [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=that%20pair%20of%20scissors%2C%20those%20scissors&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthat%20pair%20of%20scissors%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthose%20scissors%3B%2Cc0) shows, the second version is a lot more common.

Comment: "those pair of scissors" === "those scissors"? If so it's not a fair comparison.

Comment: @Pacerier, your equivalence is not correct. "that pair of scissors" === "those scissors"

Answer (score 1):

Scissors, information, software, and trousers etc. are collective nouns and they don't have any plural form. Now, how to make them 'single?' as in your case? Then, you need to ***quantify*** them by adding a few words.

> scissors can be quantified as: *a pair of scissors.* 
>  trousers (--- as above ---) 
>  information ca be quantified as *a pierce of information*

This is the reason of that *replacement*.

You surely need an article but in your case, it is following *'that,'* so it goes without the article:

> Pass me that pair of scissors

Comment: I disagree. From what I hear often. A **pair of scissors** mostly refers to two items not one, however, it can refer to one. If you need scissors you ask for scissors, if you need a pair you ask for a pair. However if you refer to three items, saying "three scissors" is wrong. You need to say "three pairs of scissors".

Comment: Yes true. "a pair of scissors" is plural form to indicate two items. It doesn't refer them as a single quantity

Comment: @starun008 Wrong! It does, but it's not as common as simply saying "scissors"

Comment: Ok. If we says "glasses" or "a pair of glasses" (I have a pair of glasses for my poor eyesight) both refer to same thing what we wear. "a pair of glasses doesn't refer two quantity (Are those your glasses on the table?). Why not same in the case of "scissors".

Comment: @SovereignSun what?...a pair of scissors refers to ***two items and not one?*** Aw...

Comment: @MaulikV Yes, I sometimes hear that

Answer (score 0):

"**Scissors**" consist of a pair of metal blades pivoted so that the sharpened edges slide against each other when the handles opposite to the pivot are closed.

> You can call the two-bladed cutting tool simply **scissors** or you can call it a **pair of scissors** neither will be wrong. However, if you refer to one unit, you should refer to it as "*pair of scissors*". If there are more that one then refer to them as "*two pairs of scissors*", "*three pairs of scissors*", etc.

Notice the difference in usage:

- Give me the (those) scissors.
- Give me a (that) pair of scissors.
- I need to buy seven pairs of scissors.
- We threw away our old scissors.
- I am using a special pair of scissors.

Comment: In that case, use of "scissors" is correct here. We don't need to replace it with "pair of scissors"

Comment: You can use either.

Comment: "Give me a (that) pair of scissors. (Either one unit or two)". I don't get why you says it can be refer to two unit also.  "I have two pairs of scissors. This one is better than that one." Or "I have a pairs of glasses. This one is better than that one." if "a pair of" can be also refer to two unit, then mentioned sentences are correct here.

Comment: "I have a pair of glasses" can mean one unit or two units. However, I think I'd understand it as "glasses" - one unit.

Comment: I disagree that a pair of scissors can be one or two pieces of cutting equivalant. I it, unequivocally, just one piece of cutting quipment. Likewise, a pair of glasses can mean one piece of optical equipment that has two lenses: it can never mean two such pieces of equipment. It could, however, be used to refer to two (probably distinctively unique) drinking glasses.

Comment: @SovereignSun ....can mean one unit or two units, again? I think you are confused between *a pair of normal nouns* and *a pair of collective nouns* to ***quantify***. The latter one *never* means two items.

Comment: @MaulikV Yeh, I've updated my answer and my rememberies.

Comment: There you go...revoked! But for most of the non-native speakers, this has been always confusing (not for me anymore! I visit ELL regularly!) :)

Comment: @MaulikV I was thinking Russian-English - unacceptable!